# Alternative to "is going to be"

Tags: verbs, future, passive-voice, will-be-going

I want to find a synonym to **"is going to be"** in a sentence like: "X is going to be outdated after Y joins X".

I could have chosen "will be", but I want something more incisive, and less "in the future"...

Comment: In fact, switching X and Y may help as in, 'Y obviates X'

Comment: More incisive but less in the future? That seems at odds. 'will be' is pretty incisive, it is definitely not now, and is definitely in the future. Also, in how many ways is 'is going to" __not__ about the future? Do you mean not so -far- in the the future?

Comment: Not sure why you want to avoid the English future ‭ te㎋u here. I guess you could use the English present ‭ te㎋u across the board, like “X gets outdated once Y joins Z”. There are also ways to express the “once ...” clause using some English present subjunctive te‭㎋u, but those a bit stilted and unnatural.  “As soon as Y should join Z, X shall be outdated.” Sounds like a contract or something, or a command to outdate it, or some such weirdness.

Comment: X will die after Y joins X.

Comment: @tchrist You keep writing "tenFu". Do you mean "tense"?

Comment: @Jay I mean [the standard OED sense of “tense”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199169), not the only-permitted ᴇʟᴜ sense of “tense”, which is considerably narrower and less useful for general discussion. Since the ***purissisamistas*** hereabouts will not condescend to consider the *OED* a valid reference work, and insist upon their own peculiar binary sense of what would otherwise be a perfectly serviceable term, I for the sake of *wit’s soul* write **te‭㎋u** with its distinctive orthography to mean the normal *OED* sense instead of their sillinesses. It recalls `/tmp/foo` … and much more.

Comment: @tchrist: Arguably ELU more than most se sites should stick to standard English! Seriously, if even Jay didn't understand you, how much more of a problem would it be for less fluent readers - now and in future?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that’s my point exactly. However, until the ban on using Standard English is lifted here and we are allowed to use the common-sense meaning espoused by the OED, I shall continue to use ***te‭㎋u***, since I am not permitted to use the Standard English word in its everyday sense, but am otherwise forced to include a multi-paragraph disclaimer to stifle the persnickety purissisamistas with their uselessly narrow-minded condescension. Plus when you think about it, ***te‭㎋u*** is really quite expressive in oh-so-many ways. That’s a bonus.

Comment: @tchrist: I'll have some of whatever you're smoking! (even if doesn't improve my ability to understand what you're saying, I'm sure it'll make everything seem much more *deep / meaningful / fascinating*! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I second that. I would have said *I'll second that* but I don't know for what reason I'm hesitant about using the simple future on this train.

Comment: For some reason "tenfu" sounds to me like some Oriental discipline, maybe a martial art, like "karate, tai chi, and ten fu". :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's the problem with *will be* but you can try *will become*, which fits a little better for this case, since it refers to a final state different from the initial.

> X will (certainly) become outdated after Y joins X.

Comment: I agree that simply using the normal English future te‭㎋u is the most natural way to express this.

Comment: Re your recent edit to the question - it might seem rude to you, but the general consensus here on ELU is that question text should *not* include things like *"Thanks!"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with the general consensus of not including things like *Thanks*. However, I can't agree on the limitation of not being able to do edits with less than 6 chars. I'd rather have my thanks removed from the edit than forcefully having to find errors or improvements that may or may not be there. And if they are not there, I wonder what the suggested course of action would be. No one can be so pedantic as to assure that every single post can be enhanced. I know this issue has been discussed on meta but it wasn't me who brought it up, at least here.

Comment: I'm no expert on these things, but I rather suspect I've made a few 1-char edits. Maybe that limit disappears when you get more rep (congrats on reaching 1K btw :)

Comment: I'm sure it will, but it just shouldn't have been there in the first place. Regarding the congrats, thanks ! I can now die in peace :)

Comment: Just thinking about your answer, and OP's wish to avoid directly referencing "the future", it occurs to me one could reasonably say *"X becomes outdated once Y joins"* - except that I cannot for the life of me imagine *any* real-world values of X and Y where any of these different permutations make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

"is ... once", as in "X is outdated once Y joins X"

Comment: *is* or *will be*?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: It will fit the sentence, but not the question.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: I've been recently in Yerevan, nice city ! :)