# Shorter version of "is going to be"

Tags: phrase-requests, future, will-be-going

I've just read question: [Alternative to "is going to be"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58002/alternative-to-is-going-to-be)

I got similar problem, but in my case I need to describe something that might happen in the future.
The sentence is "Project milestone is going to be missed." (So it will be missed if noone prevents it.)
How to write it shorter?

Comment: Your title says you want a short version of "is going to be" (definitely will happen) but your question says you need to describe something that *might* happen. Which do you want? If it's the former (definite) then I don't see what's wrong with the answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Project milestone is going to be missed." (So it will
>   be missed if no one prevents it.)

How about *project milestone is **at risk*** or

*project milestone is **at risk of being missed***?

Comment: 'Project milestone is at risk' sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comments, it seems that you are trying to introduce conditional uncertainty. I'm not certain that you can do this by simply adjusting that verb. For example, you could introduce uncertainty by switching it to *"may"*, but I believe that is not the meaning you want. *"Project milestone may be missed"* ...but it may not. There's no great impetus.

It is my opinion that the meaning you are after will almost certainly require more context. That is, you would qualify it with another clause. *"**Without x action**, project milestone will be missed"*. You could, of course, combine them: *"Without x action, project milestone **may** be missed"*, but this creates a sense of less urgency.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with what you almost already proposed?

> The Milestone Project will be missed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I would use will if I'm sure this milestone will be missed. What I want to inform is that someone needs to do something to prevent this. So the milestone will be missed or not.
Aren't there any short forms, like "is to be missed"?